# Ошибка «Двоичный оператор Multiply не определен для типов "System.Int32" и "System.Double"»

Tags: c#

```
 public static Func<double, double> Lagrang(Func<double, double> function, double a, double b, int N)
    {
        #region
        double[] x = new double[N];

        double h = (b - a) / (N-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            x[i] = a + i * h;

        double[] f = x.Select(v => function(v)).ToArray();
        #endregion

        ParameterExpression xParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "x");
        ConstantExpression NullConst= Expression.Constant(0);


        Expression resultExpression = Expression.Add(NullConst, NullConst);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            Expression chisl = Expression.Add(NullConst, NullConst);
            //Expression znam = Expression.Add(NullConst, NullConst);
            double znam = 1;

            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                if (i==j)
                    continue;

                ConstantExpression SecondParam = Expression.Constant(x[j]);
                Expression skobka = Expression.Subtract(xParam, SecondParam);
                chisl = Expression.Multiply(chisl, skobka);

                znam *= (x[i] - x[j]);
            }
            ConstantExpression ZnamConst = Expression.Constant(znam);
            ConstantExpression f_value = Expression.Constant(f[i]);

            Expression ChislMultFunc = Expression.Multiply(chisl, f_value);
            Expression L = Expression.Divide(ChislMultFunc, ZnamConst);

            resultExpression = Expression.Add(resultExpression, L);
        }

        LambdaExpression lyambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(resultExpression, xParam);
        var InterpolationLyambda = (Func<double, double>)lyambdaExpression.Compile();

        return InterpolationLyambda;
    }
```

Ругается на

```
  chisl = Expression.Multiply(chisl, skobka);
```

Дополнительные сведения:

> Двоичный оператор Multiply не определен для типов "System.Int32" и "System.Double"

Comment: Тут пытаюсь запрограммировать интерполяционный многочлен Лагранжа

Comment: Люди, которые постят код и не задают ни одного вопроса -- на что вы рассчитываете? На то, что телепаты догадаются, что вы хотели спросить? Прогосовал за закрытие.

Comment: Ругается на `chisl = Expression.Multiply(chisl, skobka);` - как ругается-то?

Comment: Дополнительные сведения: Двоичный оператор Multiply не определен для типов "System.Int32" и "System.Double".

Comment: @AK 
Учту. Думал что ошибка, для знающих, будет явной. Т.к. использую деревья выр. впервые.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь перемножить значения разных типов. Скастуйте один из них к другому. Если есть сомнения, как написать конкретное выражение - напишите его в виде лямбды и посмотрите структуру в отладчике

Comment: @kovdryavlad, так она и тебе явно указана :-)

Comment: @PashaPash, скорее надо просто заменить `Expression.Constant(0);` на `Expression.Constant(0.0);`

Comment: @PashaPash помогло.

Comment: @PashaPash
Это адекватная запись?
Expression chisl = Expression.Add(NullConst, NullConst);

Comment: @kovdryavlad не знаю, я не вникал в суть кода. может быть фикс от Grundy будет лучше.

Comment: @kovdryavlad, `Expression chisl = Expression.Add(NullConst, NullConst)` - это корректная запись, но учитывая, что `NullConst` обычный `0`, не видно смысла в этой строке, в итоге все равно 0 будет

Comment: @kovdryavlad в будущем добавляйте сообщение об ошибке в заголовок. Это здорово помогает идентифицировать вопрос как тем, кто может на него ответить, так и тем, кто столкнулся с той же проблемой.

Comment: @PashaPash ваш трюк с лямбдой и отладчиком выглядит очень интересно, но для меня, например, совсем неочевидно, что конкретно нужно сделать. У нас есть какой-нибудь хороший ответ об этом с пошаговой инструкцией?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, там стандартно, поставить точку остановки, добавить в watch и посмотреть что он выведет

Answer (score 4):

Сообщение об ошибке

> Двоичный оператор Multiply не определен для типов "System.Int32" и "System.Double"

ясно дает понять, что один из операндов `Expression.Multiply(chisl, skobka);` имеет тип "System.Int32", а второй "System.Double", что недопустимо.

При этом, `skobka` - это результат выражения `Expression.Subtract(xParam, SecondParam)`, операнды которого имеют тип double, и соответственно итоговое выражение так же имеет тип double.

`chisl` же, результат `Expression.Add(NullConst, NullConst)`, где NullConst это

```
ConstantExpression NullConst = Expression.Constant(0);
```

По умолчанию, числовые литералы имеют тип `int`, по этому данное выражение тоже будет иметь тип `int`.

Для решения, нужно передать double, для этого нужно либо использовать суффикс `d`

```
ConstantExpression NullConst = Expression.Constant(0d);
```

либо добавить точку

```
ConstantExpression NullConst = Expression.Constant(0.0);
```

либо конвертировать операнды в double перед использованием в Multiply. Для этого используется выражение [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb292051(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
chisl = Expression.Multiply(Expression.Convert(chisl,typeof(double)), Expression.Convert(skobka, typeof(double)));
```